# Create a Specific Div Shape in CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

I would like to create this specific div shape:
[Rectangular div with a little transparent triangle at the top-center of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1kUT.png)

I have read on how to create custom shapes but I really don't get the logic.. Can someone here kindly help me on the drawing of such a shape or redirect me to a web that explain really well the logic behind it? thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The idea is a box with zero width and height. The actual width and height of the arrow is determined by the width of the border.
there is a great and simple tutorial at [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) website with  little animation that shows exactly how it all happens.

Answer (score 0):

you can design it like:

```css
.rect {
            background: black;
            height: 50px;
            width: 150px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .rect:after {
            content: "";
            background: #ffffff;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); 
            -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
            -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); 
            -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top:-35px;
            right: 50px;
            
        }
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by:

HTML:

`<div class="block">
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
 </div>`

CSS:

```
.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;

    border-top: 20px solid #fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
}

.block{
   background-color:black;
   height: 200px;
   position:relative;
}
```